# Variable turns nil when inside a function

Tags: go

Why the `db` variable is `nil` in the `getBooks` function?

```
package main

import (
    ...
)

var db *sql.DB

func init() {
    gotenv.Load()
}

func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", os.Getenv("ELEPHANTSQL_URL"))
    err = db.Ping()
    fmt.Println(db, err)

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/books", getBooks).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", router))
}

func getBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if db == nil {
        log.Print("!!!!!!!!!!")
        os.Exit(2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `:=` you're declaring a new `db` variable inside the `main()` scope instead of assigning to the `db` variable at the package scope.

You must either use just `=` or use another name than `db`.

Try this:

```golang
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("postgres", os.Getenv("ELEPHANTSQL_URL"))
```